# Submit my form with new value when I change select form value

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am working on a form where the select value is changing based on a click

When I click on `h3`, my select option value is changing but it's submitting the form with previous select option  value. I want my new value to submit.

```js
jQuery(".monthsele").click(function() {
  var monthval = jQuery(this).find("span").attr('umval');
  jQuery("#formselect #mons option:selected").remove();

  jQuery("#formselect #mons option[value=" + monthval + "]").attr('selected', 'selected');

  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery('form#formselect').submit();
  }, 1000);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formselect" id="formselect" method="post" action="">

  <select id="mons" name="mons">
        
      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
                  
     </select>

  <button type="submit" name="formselect_form" id="formselect_form" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
</form>

<h3 class="col-sm-4 monthsele"><span umval="2" class="pull-left">2</span></h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
jQuery("#formselect #mons option[value="+monthval+"]").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

try

```
jQuery("#formselect #mons").val(monthval).change();
```

Check this example:

```js
jQuery(".monthsele").click(function() {
  var monthval = jQuery(this).find("span").attr('umval');
  jQuery("#formselect #mons").val(monthval).change();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="formselect" id="formselect" method="post" action="">

  <select id="mons" name="mons">
        
      <option value="1" selected>1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
                  
     </select>

  <button type="submit" name="formselect_form" id="formselect_form" class="btn btn-default">submit</button>
</form>

<h3 class="col-sm-4 monthsele"><span umval="2" class="pull-left">2</span></h3>
```

Comment: okk sorted with submit button trigger jquery. Thanks for your help:)

Comment: You can upvote and accept the answer if it helps you.